# How to publish an event in Automatonymous state machine after each event gets completed?

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit, automatonymous

I have an Automatonymous state machine with a bunch of events.
I would like to publish each event after the previous one completes. I know I could publish it in the consumer of each event, but some of them might be reused in different state machines so I would like to declare it in the state machine definition. Here's what I have now:

```
public class TestStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<TestState>
    {
        public State StepOneCompleted { get; set; }
        public State StepTwoCompleted { get; set; }
        public State StepThreeCompleted { get; set; }

        public Event<ProcessStepOne> ProcessStepOne { get; set; }
        public Event<ProcessStepTwo> ProcessStepTwo { get; set; }
        public Event<ProcessStepThree> ProcessStepThree { get; set; }

        public TestStateMachine()
        {
            InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

            Initially(When(ProcessStepOne)
                .Publish(context => new ProcessStepTwo
                {
                    CorrelationId = context.Data.CorrelationId,
                })
                .TransitionTo(StepOneCompleted));
            During(StepOneCompleted,
                When(ProcessStepTwo)
                    .Publish(context => new ProcessStepThree
                    {
                        CorrelationId = context.Data.CorrelationId,
                    })
                    .TransitionTo(StepTwoCompleted));
            During(StepTwoCompleted, When(ProcessStepThree).TransitionTo(StepThreeCompleted));
        }
    }
```

With this definition second step gets published while step one is still being executed and third step while second step is being executed. I would like to make sure that step one completes, then step two gets published, then step two completes and step three gets published. I tried to use `WhenLeave` behaviour but it expects a State, not an Event so I don't have access to `context.Data` and CorrelationId will not be only variable that I will pass between steps.

Is there a possible way to achieve that within state machine definition?

Comment: If you are following steps as part of a transaction with compensation, you really should be using a [routing slip](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/courier/). Routing slips are designed for sequential activities, support compensation, and allow event subscriptions to monitor success, failure, progress.

Comment: Alright, I guess that's a point for routing slip. I'll go with it then, thanks.